# Passing in data to my ejs view when redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, ejs

I am trying to send data from my login page to my home page when the user is redirecting to the home page, so that i can use in information in the home ejs file.

Here is my code:

```
    module.exports = function (app) {

        app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
            var data = {
                "email": req.body.email,
                "password": req.body.password
            }

            functions.callAPI("api link", data, function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    var response = {
                        "status": 400,
                        "message": error,
                        "data": null
                    }
                    res.render('login', { response: response });
                } else {
                    var response = result;
                    if (response.status === 400) {
                        res.render('login', { response: response });
                    } else {
                        req.session.token = response.data[0].token;
                        req.session.id = response.data[0].id
                        res.redirect('/home', { response: response }); //this is where i what to pass the data.
                    }
                }
            });


        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, say, the callback to your app.get('/home') is res.render('home')

Change
`res.redirect('/home', { response: response });`

to
`res.render('home', { response: response });`

edit 1 :

Since your comment indicate that your get('/home') route is not simply rendering home, do it in this way:

In this module handling app.post('/login'), instead of incorporating the whole route logic, return the callback only, name it as loginCallback in server.js (or app.js or index.js)

And make another module to return the callback of app.get('/home'), name it as homeCallback, make it accept one more argument, for the response, with a default parameter as empty object.

Now this loginCallback will call the homeCallback, passing the third argument.

This can achieve your purpose.

Comment: this  `res.render('home', { response: response });` will only render home view but the route will still be login route not home route

Comment: Then do it in this way:.... (cannot use new line here at comment, i will edit my answer, just a min).

Comment: @codabae I have edited my answer. Please try. If you still don't understand it, please show your entry point js scripts and the app.get('/home') js scripts, so I can be more detailed.